# Keras functional API slower than Sequential / Not improving

Tags: python-3.x, keras, lstm

SOLVED!(Had to set trainable=true in the sequential model)

I am currently changing my Keras model from Sequential to the functional API. While the Sequential model does improve to an accuracy of 1 after like 10 epochs, the functional API model does not even reach 0.7 and does not further improve. Apart from the Input layer, both nets should be the same.

Sequential:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(20000, 256,input_length = 30))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.4))
model.add(LSTM(256, dropout=0.3, recurrent_dropout=0.3))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001),metrics = ['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
```

Output is:

```
    _________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_6 (Embedding)      (None, 30, 256)           5120000   
_________________________________________________________________
spatial_dropout1d_5 (Spatial (None, 30, 256)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_5 (LSTM)                (None, 256)               525312    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 257       
=================================================================
Total params: 5,645,569
Trainable params: 5,645,569
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

For the functional API:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(31,))
embed = Embedding(20000, 256, trainable=False)(inputs)
drop = (SpatialDropout1D(0.4))(embed)
lstm = LSTM(256, dropout=0.3, recurrent_dropout=0.3)(drop)
acti = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(lstm)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=acti)
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001),metrics = ['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
```

Result

```
Model: "model_5"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_8 (InputLayer)         (None, 31)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding_7 (Embedding)      (None, 31, 256)           5120000   
_________________________________________________________________
spatial_dropout1d_6 (Spatial (None, 31, 256)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_6 (LSTM)                (None, 256)               525312    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 257       
=================================================================
Total params: 5,645,569
Trainable params: 525,569
Non-trainable params: 5,120,000
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

Have I overseen something or can someone explain my results?

Comment: Why is it input size `30` for sequential api and `31` for functional api?

Comment: That was apparently a typo after copying the code, but thank you anyway. I solved the problem now, I had to set trainable=true in the Sequential model. I have simply overseen that.